# Why option -m32 is not working on my linux operating system?

Tags: c, compilation

I met a compile problem, these codes are from same professor, but my classmates able to compile it but me, that is what I try to find out.

I used my Surface Pro1(intel i5 4G Ram) with a LinuxMint 18.2 64bit OS, gcc version 5.4.0, but some how I cannot compile my codes with command `gcc -m32 ./ch2ex3.c`. Here is the error:

```
fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory, compilation terminated.
```

but if use same command without option `-m32` working fine, but it gives a "Segmentation fault" at the end of my program, when it should print "NULL" instead.

**Question,** why this option `-m32` does not working with my computer?

This is the code that I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *FP; // a global pointer

main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])
{ 
    int a,b,c;

    printf("enter main: &argc=%x &argv=%x\n", &argc, &argv);
    printf("&a=%x &b=%x &c=%x\n", &a, &b, &c);

    a=1; b=2; c=3;
    A(a,b);
    printf("exit main\n");
}

int A(int x, int y)
{ 
    int d,e,f;
    printf("enter A\n");
    d=4; e=5; f=6;
    B(d,e);
    printf("exit A\n");
}

int B(int x, int y)
{ 
    int u,v,w;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int *p;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    printf("enter B\n");
    u=7; v=8; w=9;


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    p = (int *)&p;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    asm("movl %ebp, FP"); // set FP=CPU's %ebp register

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    printf("FP=%8x p=%8x\n", FP, p);
    while(FP)
    {
        printf("%8x->", FP);
        FP = (int *)*FP;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
    getchar();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    printf("exit B\n");
}
```

Comment: You need the `gcc-multiarch` package, not just `gcc`, in order to pull in all the libraries. Package name may vary across distros, but this specific answer is for Debian/Ubuntu (which includes Mint).

Comment: And don't ask multiple questions in the same question. Make them separate questions.

Comment: The "expected string literal" error on the Rasp is most likely because you used single quotes there (i.e. the code you show is not the code you tried to compile).

Comment: @DevSolar double quotes was cause another error: `arm ...... expected 'movl %ebp, FP' ..... bad instruction....`  something like that...

Comment: @o11c you mean I need `gcc-multiarch` on both computers? or just on Pi3?

Comment: `FP = (int *)*FP;` -- On a 64bit machine this gives me the following warning: "cast to pointer from integer of different size". `sizeof( int ) == 4` and `sizeof( int * ) == 8`. And you need multiarch when using `-m32` (because you are compiling for a different architecture than the native one).

Comment: The double quotes weren't the error, the use of x86 assembler on ARM architecture was. ARM neither has a `movl` opcode nor a register called `ebp`, hence "bad instruction". Changing the double to single quotes just hid the error. (You're giving a 13-char character constant there...)

Comment: @DevSolar got it.... what about when I use `-m32` on my Surface Pro?

Comment: What about it? Seriously. What is your actual question? You are delving deep into stack layout here, which isn't defined by the C language standard and is something very much platform-defined. I guess your *real* question is something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

my solutions is

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

if above command not working on your LinuxMint18.2, then go to `Menu -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager`, then search keyword `gcc-multilib` and `Mark for Installation` -> Apply.